# Interpolate list of tuples into VALUE clause of select statement using sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I need to join a postgresql table against a list of values that I compute frequently and outside of the database.

This seems like the type of query I'd like to make

```
SELECT id
FROM elements
JOIN (VALUES (1, 0.1), (3, 0.4), (2, 0.05)) as priorities (id, priority)
USING (id)
```

I'd like to dynamically create the `VALUES` tuples. But I can't seem to find a good way to do that with SQLAlchemy.

```
priorities = [(1, 0.1), (3, 0.4), (2, 0.05)]

engine.execute("SELECT id
                FROM elements
                JOIN (VALUES :priorities) as priorities (id, priority)
                USING (id)",
               priorities = priorities)
```

Casts `priorities` to an `ARRAY`.

Comment: If you need to use `VALUES` inside of a textual SQL query, you'll need to parameterize *each individual value* in your `VALUES` clause (i.e. `VALUES (:val1, :val2), (:val3, :val4), ...`).

Comment: You could do `JOIN unnest(:priorities) as priorities (id int, priority numeric)` or such, I think.