# PostgreSQL Values list (table constructor) with SQLAlchemy. How to for native SQL query?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use PostgreSQL Values list https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html (also known as table constructor) in Python with SQLAlchemy.

Here the SQL working in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT input_values.ticker
FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) as input_values(ticker)
```

I built a list of tickers and passing it as argument. It converted by SQLAlchecmy to

```
SELECT input_values.ticker
FROM (VALUES (%(input_values_1)s, %(input_values_2)s, %(input_values_3)s)) as input_values(ticker)
```

Which looks good if would list be used as param with IN clause. But in my case this not works. How to provide parameters list correctly?

Here the code I have:

```
import logging

from injector import inject
from sqlalchemy import bindparam
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

from database.database_connection import DatabaseConnection


class CompaniesDAO:
    FIND_NEW_QUERY = '''
            SELECT input_values.ticker
            FROM (VALUES :input_values) as input_values(ticker)
            '''

    @inject
    def __init__(self, database_connection: DatabaseConnection):
        self.__database_connection = database_connection

    def save_new(self, companies):
        tickers = ['A', 'B', 'C']
        input_values = {'input_values': tickers}
        database_engine = self.__database_connection.get_engine()
        with database_engine.connect() as connection:
            query = text(CompaniesDAO.FIND_NEW_QUERY)
            query = query.bindparams(bindparam('input_values', expanding=True))
            result = connection.execute(query, input_values)
            new_tickers = [row[0] for row in result]
            logging.info(new_tickers)
```

I saw few related discussions like [VALUES clause in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858291/values-clause-in-sqlalchemy) and checked current solution like https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/PGValues. However, I not see solution for native SQL query. Is there any?

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45474738/5320906) - I'm not sure there is a better way as yet, assuming you are using psycopg(2) as the driver.

Comment: I could build query string by including parameters inline, however this does not best approach. This way I could make my request with any of Psycopg2 or SQLAlchemy. As soon as I started with SQLAlchemy I would like to avoid the Psycopg2, just to not make my app over complicated.

Comment: Pass the parameter as a comma-separate list and `select e as ticker form unnest(string_to_array(:input_values, ',')) e;` or `select e as ticker form unnest(('{'||:input_values||'}')::text[]) e;`

Comment: I have not used SQLAlchemy in while but this [VALUES](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.values) looks promising.

Comment: If you want to use `psycopg2` directly then: `execute_values(cur, 'select * from (VALUES %s) AS test(fld_1, fld_2, fld_3)',  [(1, 2, 2), (3, 4,4)]) ` where `execute_values` comes from [psycopg.extras execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers).

Comment: @Adrian I am so sorry, but you misunderstood my question. I do not want to use Psycopg2. I asked about SQLAlchemy, not to mention link to VALUES you posted is the same method I mentioned in my post. I am aware of it. I am looking for native SQL query support.

Comment: @Stefanov Is your proposed solution SQL injection-safe?

Comment: When using as a prepared statement it is generally SQL injection safe. Otherwise any parameterized query that is executed using text interpolation in one form or another is a potential risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case, the Table Value Constructor (TVC) values should be a list of tuples, not a list of scalar values

```py
tickers = [('A',), ('B',), ('C',)]
```

from which we can then build the TVC (VALUES construct)

```py
tvc = values(
    column("ticker", String),
    name="input_values"
).data(tickers)
```

Now the easiest way to get the query is simply

```py
qry = select(text("input_values.ticker")).select_from(tvc)
```

with which we can do

```
engine.echo = True
with engine.begin() as conn:
    results = conn.execute(qry).all()
    """
    SELECT input_values.ticker 
    FROM (VALUES (%(param_1)s), (%(param_2)s), (%(param_3)s)) AS input_values (ticker)
    [no key 0.00036s] {'param_1': 'A', 'param_2': 'B', 'param_3': 'C'}
    """
    print(results)
    """
    [('A',), ('B',), ('C',)]
    """
```

However, if you *really* want to use a literal SQL query you could also do

```py
tvc = values(
    column("ticker", String),
    name="input_values",
    literal_binds=True,
).data(tickers)

qry = text(
    "SELECT input_values.ticker "
    f"FROM ({tvc.compile(engine)}) AS input_values (ticker)"
)

engine.echo = True
with engine.begin() as conn:
    results = conn.execute(qry).all()
    """
    SELECT input_values.ticker FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) AS input_values (ticker)
    [generated in 0.00026s] {}
    """
    print(results)
    """
    [('A',), ('B',), ('C',)]
    """
```

Or if your TVC had a lot of columns and you didn't want to type them all out you could let SQLAlchemy build the column list for you

```py
tvc = values(
    column("ticker", String),
    name="input_values",
    literal_binds=True,
).data(tickers)

basic_select = select(text("*")).select_from(tvc)
tvc_compiled = str(basic_select.compile(engine))[15:]
print(tvc_compiled)
# (VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) AS input_values (ticker)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second solution with SQL string looks promising. Is it SQL injection safe? The first one is easy to find and it worked for me. The benefit of native SQL is it looks more readable for somebody not very familiar with SQLAlchecmy. Also when I have tested complex native SQL query, it should take a bit less time to use i as is, instead of translate to SQLAlchemy methods.

Comment: SQLAlchemy does its best to protect us from SQL injection vulnerabilities, but it is always best to avoid using literal binds with untrusted/unsanitized input.

Comment: Hello. I am sorry was not able to run the solution earlier. I tried the second variant with native SQL and it worked well. Thank you!